# Insert из select'а с добавлением поля (TSQL)

Tags: sql

Здравствуйте, при написании кода на TSQL возникла проблема, не смог найти ответ в гугле:(

Есть 2 таблицы:

- AA (ID int, somestring char) и
- BB (ID int, somestring char, somedate datetime)

также есть инициализированная переменная @thedate типа datetime.

Как нужно написать Insert, чтобы в результате его выполнения все записи из AA были скопированы в BB: поля ID и somestring соответственно, а поле somedate было заполнено значением переменной @thedate?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Insert into BB
select *, @thedate from AA
```

Answer (score 0):

На всякий случай лучше явно перечислить, что выбираете из AA и куда вставляете в BB, иначе при изменении структуры таблиц запрос упадет.

Советую так:

```
Insert into BB
(ID, somestring, somedate)
select ID, somestring, @thedate from AA
```